# Azure Functions - error MSB4057: The target "MsDeployPublish" does not exist in the project

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-functions

I am trying to **build the azure function app project using "msbuild"** -
 Build Tools for VS 2017 - from PowerShell (https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/?q=msbuild)

Command-

```
            $pubxmlFilePath = (Get-Location).Path + "\" + "functionapp.pubxml"        

            $msbuildParams = '/t:MsDeployPublish /P:Configuration=Release `
                              /P:Configuration="Any CPU" `
                              /p:PublishProfile=' +$pubxmlFilePath + ' `
                              /p:Password=password'    

            $deployFunctionApp = '$msbuild' +" " + $functionAppProjectPath + `
                                  " " + $msbuildParams

            Invoke-Expression "& $deployFunctionApp"
```

but it is throwing the below exception-

**error MSB4057: The target "MsDeployPublish" does not exist in the project**

Reference links followed:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0f0f4bf0-7e9b-40e5-836a-11c97357a2d1/deploy-azure-functions-via-cli?forum=AzureFunctions

Could you please help me out?

Thanks,
Suraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed your reference link and have made some tests on your script with a c# Azure function. It works on my side.

I changed the parameter values and found only two parameters caused exception you met. Here are the parameters:

- `$functionAppProjectPath`
  It should be assigned the path where the project files locates.(For c#, both the path of .sln and .csproj file are ok).
- `$pubxmlFilePath` Make sure the file name is correct. Besides, the property `/P:PublishProfile` needs only file name, the folder path is unnecessary. On my side, the build succeeded even though the folder path was incorrect.

If it doesn't work for you, you can change `/t:MsDeployPublish` to`/P:DeployOnBuild=True`. This also works on my side.

You may also need to change `/P:Configuration="Any CPU"` to `/P:Platform="Any CPU"`, since on my side it caused another exception-`error MSB4126: The specified solution configu
ration "Any CPU|Any CPU" is invalid.`

Comment: Thansk Jerry!  Yes true - /P:PublishProfile needs only profile name and that too in this format - <SiteName - Web Deploy.pubxml>. Worked finally for me :)